# Logstash dynamic variable not working with rabbitmq plugin

Tags: logstash

I am trying to process Nginx access log with the help of Logstash (Version 2.1.3)

On the basis of different endpoints found in Nginx access log, I want to send data in different queues or sometimes in different RabbitMQ Servers.

Here is my Logstash configuration:

```
input {
  stdin {}
}
filter {

grok {
   match => { "message" => "(?<status>.*?)!~~!(?<req_tm>.*?)!~~!(?<time>.*?)!~~!(?<req_method>.*?)!~~!(?<req_uri>.*)" }
   tag_on_failure => ["first_grok_failed"]
}
if "/endpoint1" in [req_uri] {
      mutate { add_field => { "[queue]" => "endpoint_one" } }
      mutate { add_field => { "[rmqshost]" => "10.10.10.1" } }
}
else if "/endpoint2" in [req_uri] {
    mutate { add_field => { "[queue]" => "endpoint_two" } }
    mutate { add_field => { "[rmqshost]" => "10.10.10.2" } }
}
else {
    mutate { add_field => { "[queue]" => "endpoint_other" } }
    mutate { add_field => { "[rmqshost]" => "10.10.10.3" } }
}
}
output {
   rabbitmq {
            exchange => "%{[queue]}_exchange"
            exchange_type => "direct"
            host => "%{[rmqshost]}"
            key => "%{[queue]}_key"
            password => "mypassword"
            user=>"myuser"
            vhost=>"myvhost"
            durable=>false

    }

   stdout { 
    codec  => rubydebug 
   }
}
```

- In filter section of above configuration, I add dynamic variable "queue" and "rmqshost".
- In output section, I tried using those varibles inside rabbitmq plugin
  block.

I am getting following error which shows that "rmqshost" variable have not got replaced.

```
Connection to %{[rmqshost]}:5672 refused: host unknown 
{:exception=>"MarchHare::ConnectionRefused", :backtrace=>
["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-
java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:473:in `converting_rjc_exceptions_to_ruby'", 
"/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:500:in `new_connection_impl'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:136:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:109:in `connect'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-java/lib/march_hare.rb:20:in `connect'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-mixin-rabbitmq_connection-2.3.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/rabbitmq_connection.rb:137:in `connect'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-mixin-rabbitmq_connection-2.3.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/rabbitmq_connection.rb:94:in `connect!'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-rabbitmq-3.0.7-java/lib/logstash/outputs/rabbitmq.rb:40:in `register'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:192:in `start_outputs'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:102:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.3-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:165:in `execute'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.3-java/lib/logstash/runner.rb:90:in `run'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.3-java/lib/logstash/runner.rb:95:in `run'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.22/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in `initialize'"], :level=>:error}
```

I am running logstash as follows:

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/nginx-filter.conf
```

with following sample data:

```
200!~~!0.004!~~!14/Apr/2017:05:15:27 +0000!~~!GET!~~!/endpoint1?key1=val1
200!~~!0.004!~~!14/Apr/2017:05:17:25 +0000!~~!GET!~~!/endpoint2?key1=val2
```

Answer (score 1):

The sprintf replacement only works for the key field in the rabbitmq output plugin.

```
@hare_info.exchange.publish(message, :routing_key => event.sprintf(@key), :properties => symbolize(@message_properties.merge(:persistent => @persistent)))
```

The actual connection is established using https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-mixin-rabbitmq_connection, which does not provide the option to replace the host via variables:

```
:hosts => @host
```

So this is currently not supported, only the key field might be replaced by logstash variables.

Comment: Thanks! I also did some research and found that only routing key can be dynamic.